# Python subprocess.Popen and asynchronous output

Tags: python, asynchronous, subprocess

I have simple Python script to execute test suite both under Windows and Linux.
Every test writes its output to separate file.
I use **subprocess.Popen** class to execute shell command in a cycle.

Every shell command starts like that:

```
def system_execute(self, command, path, out_file):
    params_list = command.split(' ') 
    file_path = os.path.join(path, out_file)
    f = open(file_path, "w")
    subprocess.Popen(params_list, stdout=f)
    f.close()
```

It works fine, but script finishes its work **before** all output files have been written.
Actually, I getting hundreds of zero-size files, and it takes some time to finish writing output and close handles.
Could anyone explain the reason why it works so strange, and is there a synchronous way to do the same job?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Before `f.close()`, you have to `wait()` for our subprocess.

```
def system_execute(self, command, path, out_file):
    params_list = command.split(' ') 
    file_path = os.path.join(path, out_file)
    f = open(file_path, "w")
    sp = subprocess.Popen(params_list, stdout=f)
    sp.wait()
    f.close()
```

or just

```
def system_execute(self, command, path, out_file):
    params_list = command.split(' ') 
    file_path = os.path.join(path, out_file)
    f = open(file_path, "w")
    subprocess.call(params_list, stdout=f)
    f.close()
```

(or, for easier file handling,

```
[...]
    with open(file_path, "w") as f:
        subprocess.call(params_list, stdout=f)
```